# connect ethereum mist wallet with ethereum local private network

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain

I am new to mist wallet

I had installed mist wallet and I want to connect mist wallet to private network

What are the steps do i need to follow to connect ethereum mist wallet with ethereum local private network??

Answer (score 1):

You must run mist with `--rpc` option which represent your private network node, for example:

```
mist --rpc http://YOUR_PRIVATE_NODE_IP:8545
```